# div растягивает картинку внутри img

Tags: html, css

Есть `div`, который имеет ширину 400px, и в нем есть тег `img`. Когда я загружаю квадратную картинку, он ее растягивает, а мне нужно, чтобы она было **не растянута**

Как можно поправить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: есть div который имеет ширину 400px и в нем есть тег img, когда я загружают квадратную картинку он его растягивает а мне нужно чтобы оно было НЕ розтягунта

Answer (score 0):

Как прямоугольную картинку обратить в квадратную, немного ужав ее измерения, с помощью `Javascript`? Приведу простой пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").on("change", e => { // Вешаем обработчик на input
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function() {
                    var side = Math.min(img.height, img.width); // Выбираем меньшую сторону изображения
                    $("canvas").width(side).height(side); // Устанавливаем размер canvas равным стороне изображения
                    $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0); // Отрисовываем ужатую картинку
                    // $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, side, side, 0, 0, side, side); // Отрисовываем обрезанную картинку
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]); // Читаем выбранные данные  
        });
    });
```

```css
canvas, input {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<canvas></canvas>
<input type="file" >
```

---

**UPD:**
После обновления Вашего вопроса смысл изменился, мягко говоря, кардинально. 
Для того, чтобы изображения не растягивалось, Вам достаточно указать у тега `img` его размеры, использовать `js` тут бессмысленно! Пример с использованием данной картинки (400х400):

[image: луна]

```css
div {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: red;
}
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6coC.jpg">
</div>
```

Как можно увидеть из сниппета, ничто и нигде не растягивается, пусть ширина `div` и превосходит таковое же измерение `img`